# Color of light in the custom shader

Tags: three.js

I added lighting to my scene with

```
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff); 
scene.add(ambientLight);

// and directional light as
const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x808080, 0.5);
```

and in my custom shader i added the light by this:

```
 uniforms1 = {
        diffuseTexture: { type: "t", value: texture },
        heightScale: { type: "f", value: _scaleHeight },
      };

      uniforms1 = THREE.UniformsUtils.merge([
        THREE.UniformsLib["lights"],
        uniforms1,
      ]);

      console.log(uniforms1);

      _meshMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: uniforms1,
        vertexShader: terrainShader._VS,
        fragmentShader: terrainShader._FS,
        lights: true,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      });
```

but when i console _meshMaterial i get this
[image]

i am passing white color so i dont understand why it is getting 3.14 as color value in uniform and the directional light color is also does not seem correct !!

Is there any help i can get to understand whats going on !!

Comment: You seem to be getting pi and pi/4 for your ambient light color and directional light color.

Comment: thank you for response i dont understand why i am getting that value in uniform ?

Comment: Looks like there's some mess-up with uniform stuff. Look at the other uniforms. Is there something wrong with them?

Comment: no, when i put  renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true; it becomes correct value i dont understand why

Comment: The artist-friendly factor of PI is by convention. For an explanation as to why it is artist-friendly, see https://seblagarde.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/pi-or-not-to-pi-in-game-lighting-equation/.